# MySQL query dates from TimeStamp

Tags: mysql

I have a column with a timestamp in milliseconds and I would like to know how can I make one query to display a list like this without duplicates

```
May 13, 2014
May 08, 2014
May 06, 2014
May 04, 2014
```

there are about a hundred records in some days so that's why I need to display unique days

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(your_timestamp_column,'%Y %D %M') FROM table where YourLogicHere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that should be fine

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(your_timestamp_column/1000,'%M %d, %Y') FROM your_table;
```

more details [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: its not displaying anything maybe cus its like this? '1394647007306'

Comment: should have specified that you did not use mysql timestamps aka unixtime. anyway, dividing by 1000 should fix that for you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct DATE_FORMAT(`datetime_col,'%M %d, %Y') FROM `table_name`
```

Answer (score 0):

by using /1000 I was able to get what I needed

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(your_timestamp_column/1000,'%M %d, %Y') FROM your_table;
```